# Why is the code from Before Group executed before each test in group?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

My goal is to stop the browser from restarting before each test belonging a certain group. 
I have a GroupObject (as described in https://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization) that listens to the events of test group "pay_form":

```
<?php

namespace Group;

class PayForm extends \Codeception\GroupObject
{
    public static $group = "pay_form";

    public function _before(\Codeception\Event\TestEvent $e)
    {
      var_dump("BEFORE GROUP!");
      $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_reconfigure(['restart' => 
      false]);
    }
}
```

codeception.yml:

```
extensions:
enabled:
    - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
    - Group\PayForm
```

The problem is, the browser restarts in each test regardless, and I also see "BEFORE GROUP" in my console in each test.

Why is the code from _before executed in each test, not once before a group of tests?

And is there another way stop the browser from restarting between tests only in a certain group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the code from _before executed in each test, not once before a group of tests?

1. Tests aren't ordered by group.
2. `_before` hook is executed before each test, `_beforeSuite` hook is executed before suite. There is no `_beforeGroup` hook - https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Hooks

> And is there another way stop the browser from restarting between tests only in a certain group?

How about moving those tests to a different suite?